# Persist firebase auth state react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

i am building a react native app and i noticed that firebase does not persist auth state by default so a user has to login again any time they exit the app. So i tried doing it manually according to their documentation but it doesn't seem to work for me.

this is where i try to set persist state

```
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, sendPasswordResetEmail, setPersistence, inMemoryPersistence} from 'firebase/auth';


 onSignIn(props) {
    const auth = getAuth();
      const { email, password } = this.state
      setPersistence(auth,inMemoryPersistence).then(() => { 

      if(email.trim().length == 0 && password.trim.length == 0){
        Alert.alert(
          "",
          "Fields can't be empty",
          [
            
            { text: "OK") }
          ])
     }else {


      signInWithEmailAndPassword( auth, email, password)
      .then((result) => {

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        
      })
    } 
  })

}
```

and this is where i check for auth state

```
 componentDidMount() {

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  
  if (!user){
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: false,
      loaded: true,
  
    })
  }else {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: true,
      loaded: true,
    })
  }
})
```

please i have been on this for weeks and have even tried using async storage but none works for me. at this point i really need help. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who is still struggling, here is how I've done it:

> **FirebaseConfig.ts**

```
import { initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import {  initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth/react-native";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
const firebaseConfig = {YOUR CONFIG};

// Initialize Firebase
export const FIREBASE_APP = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const FIREBASE_AUTH = initializeAuth(FIREBASE_APP, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});
export const FIREBASE_DB = getFirestore(FIREBASE_APP);
```

Now just use your `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function normally. Without any `setPersistance`.

Not sure if this method works on web aswell, probably not.

For react-native web:

```
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, setPersistence,browserLocalPersistence} from 'firebase/auth';
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from '../../FirebaseConfig';

setPersistence(FIREBASE_AUTH, browserLocalPersistence)
```

**Reference:** https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6050#issuecomment-1119131377

Comment: Thx a lot. My problem was with `getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)` - unfortunately it wasnt defined inside of the props for `initializeAuth`

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation on [`inMemoryPersistence`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#inmemorypersistence) it means:

> An implementation of Persistence of type 'NONE'.

Which the documentation guide on [types of auth persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#supported_types_of_auth_state_persistence) further explains as:

> `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE`
> `'none'`
> Indicates that the state will only be stored in memory and will be cleared when the window or activity is refreshed.

According to last link, you should instead use:

> `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL`
> `'local'`
> Indicates that the state will be **persisted even when the browser window is closed or the activity is destroyed in React Native**. An explicit sign out is needed to clear that state. Note that Firebase Auth web sessions are single host origin and will be persisted for a single domain only.

So by checking back in the reference docs, you'll want to use [`reactNativeLocalPersistence`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#reactnativelocalpersistence) for that

Comment: thanks but when i try this i get an error `@firebase/auth: Auth (9.6.11): INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition`

Comment: "when i try this" is hard to help with. Did you search for the error message already? It seems to have come up a few times. If you can't figure this problem out, edit your question to provide an update with what you tried.