# authUser becomes null once the application is refreshed in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I got these code snippets and three different javascript files
The console.log prints out the authUser information but once I refresh the application it gives me a null

The first one is the firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
import "firebase/compat/firestore"
// other services is needed
const firebaseConfig = {
  // firebase configuration
};


let app;
if (firebase.apps.length === 0){
    app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}else{
    app = firebase.app();
}
const db = app.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();


export {db, auth};
```

the second file is register.js

```
const register = () => {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(authUser => {
            authUser.user.updateProfile({
                displayName: name,
            })
            
        })
        .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
    }
```

and the third one is login.js and here where the bug starts

```
useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) =>{
            console.log(authUser)
            if(authUser){
                navigation.replace("Home")
            }
        })
        return unsubscribe;
    }, []);
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist firebase auth state react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74420027/persist-firebase-auth-state-react-native)