# Auth user is undefined on restart of React application

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am develop application using react native and use firebase for user authentication.but when i restart application auth is get undefined so user is automatically sign out how to avoid this..I use many options but nothing works.

For the manage navigations i use useAuth.tx

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, User } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();

export function useAuth() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState<User>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeFromAuthStateChanged = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
   if (user) {
    // User is signed in
    setUser(user);
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    setUser(undefined);
  }
}, (error) => {
  console.error("Auth state change error:", error);
});

    return unsubscribeFromAuthStateChanged;
  }, []);

  return {
    user,
  };
}
```

always getting user is undefined

I want this to manage my navigations

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '../hooks/useAuth';
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

import FinderStack from './FinderStack';
import DonorStack from './DonorStack';
import AuthStack from './AuthStack';

const firestore = getFirestore();
export default function RootNavigation() {
    const { user } = useAuth();
    console.log(user)

    const [isFinder, setIsFinder] = useState(false);
    const [isDonor, setIsDonor] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUserType = async () => {
            if (user) {
                try {
                    const userDoc = await getDoc(doc(firestore, 'users', user.uid));
                    if (userDoc.exists()) {
                        const userData = userDoc.data();
                        setIsFinder(userData.isFinder);
                        setIsDonor(userData.isDonor);
                    } else {
                        console.log('User document does not exist');
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error fetching user document:', error);
                }
            }
        };

        fetchUserType();
    }, [user]);


    if (user) {
        if (isFinder) {
            return <FinderStack />;
        } else if (isDonor) {
            return <DonorStack />;
        }
    } else {
        return <AuthStack />;
    }

    // If user or userType is not loaded yet, return a loading indicator or a splash screen
    return <></>;
}
```

this is use for user authentication

```
const Login = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation(); // Get navigation object
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, inputs.email, inputs.password)
      .then(async userCredential => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        try {
          const docRef = doc(firestore, 'users', user.uid);
          const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

          if (docSnap.exists()) {
            const userData = docSnap.data();
            if (userData.isFinder) {
              
              AsyncStorage.setItem('userType', 'finder');
              AsyncStorage.setItem('loginStatus', 'true');
              setLoading(false);
              ToastAndroid.show('Login Successful', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
              navigation.navigate('FinderHomeScreen');
            } else if (userData.isDonor) {
              AsyncStorage.setItem('userType', 'donor');
              AsyncStorage.setItem('loginStatus', 'true');
              setLoading(false);
              ToastAndroid.show('Login Successful', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
              navigation.navigate('DonorHomeScreen');
            } else {
              setError('Invalid user type');
            }
          } else {
            setError('User data not found');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error getting user document:', error);
          setError('An error occurred');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Firebase authentication error:', error);
        setError('Incorrect email or password');
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "auth is get undefined" means here. Can you point out what variable on what line is `undefined`?

Comment: The default auth behavior is to persist a user's session even after the user closes the browser. Could you please share the code snippet on how you're signing-in the user? Do you, by any chance, implement Authentication State Persistence?

Comment: I tried this on my end and I wasn't able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @looptheloop88 i use this in react-native for mobile app i didn't implement Authentication State, Is it must ?? And how i do that actually sry i am beginner so trying to figure this on my own so,didn't have much knowledge  about react-native

Comment: It would help a lot if you could share your code implementation for user authentication.

Comment: This might be related to the issue you're encountering: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74420027/6523173